# expression language in combobox on xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

On an xpage I have a combobox where the default value is set via expression language:

```
defaultValue="#{strings.field_mandate}"
```

this populates the correct value.

if I compute the Disabled property of the combobox and compute the value of the combobox in a computed text control via:

```
getComponent("mandate").getValue()
```

I get a strange behaviour.

Initially the combobox is Disabled and the computed value is correct (value from the strings.properties file). However if I switch the value of the Disabled to false the computed text value becomes literally #{strings.field_mandate}.

Why is this and how can I avoid this?

```
<xp:comboBox id="mandate" value="#{ds.mandate}" defaultValue="#{strings.field_mandate}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="#{strings.field_mandate}" itemValue="null"/>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getListMandates();}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:setSelectedMandateValues();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `getComponent().getValue()`. Computation should always happen to the value the component is bound to. So bind it to a scoped variable and set that one to your initial value. That should mitigate the issue